# How to configure wordpress in a subdirectory of a domain while main directory contain a nextjs project?(EC2, Ubuntu20, Nginx server)

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, next.js

I developed a Nextjs project (say [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) hosted on EC2 Ubuntu20 with Nginx server. Now I want the BLOG part to implement in wordpress in a subdirectory (say [www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog)).
I need help in configuration part of Ubuntu and Nginx. Also, need to know in which folder I should install the wordpress package.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @rupam did you found the solution

Comment: I’m looking for the same. Find a solution?

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: Maybe this could help - https://anshukattri.in/technology/nextjs-wordpress-subfolder-apache/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using rewrites in the `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "http://mywordpresssite.com/",
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-wordpress-nginx-ubuntu) instructions to install WordPress, PHP, and other configurations,

I remember for installing PHP, I had some errors,

this was the initial command,

```
 apt-get install php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm php7.2-mysql php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml php7.2-gd php7.2-curl
```

so I removed all 7.2 like this to install the latest version of PHP:

```
 apt-get install php php-cli php-fpm php-mysql php-json php-opcache php-mbstring php-xml php-gd php-curl
```

and it worked.

so the instructions were for installing WordPress on a domain and I had to change my Nginx config in order to make it work on a subdirectory.

your WordPress file should be in the same folder as the `alias` in the config,
that is where nginx will look for `index.php`

nginx config:

```
    location /blog {
        alias      /var/www/public-html/blog;
        index     index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }


        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }

    }

    location @blog {
        rewrite /blog/(.*)$ /blog/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```

also, make sure to add the below code to wp-config.php. otherwise, internal links in WordPress, won't have the `/blog`.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com/blog' );

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com/blog' );
```